# RowItem saved on Tab don't proceed to next editable item Flex Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, focus, row

I'm using a Flex datagrid where only 1 rowItem is editable. All the other row items are non editable. When I edit the value of the row, and press ENTER or TAB the focus is send to the next editable item in the datagrid. In this case the editable field on the next datagrid row.

I don't want this standard behaviour... I don't want the focus to be processed to the next editable item. Since the data is saved instant, it's quite strange that the focus is given to the next field. The focus has to be remained on the item that was edited.

I'm not quite sure how to get this done! Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks in advance for pointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a quick solution for this issue.
By manually setting the editedItemPosition property of the datagrid, the focus is not changed to the next editable cell item in the datagrid but to the index that we manually supply.

Add a function to the datagrid tag:

```
itemEditValueCommit="itemEditValueCommitHandler(event)"
```

in the ItemEditValueCommit function you can set the editedItemPosition  manually:

```
[datagrid].editedItemPosition = {rowIndex: event.cell.rowInfo.rowPositionInfo.rowIndex, columnIndex: 0};
```

The rowIndex is the datagrid line that we just edited.
The columnIndex can be any ColumnIndex of your datagrid!